# Comparing values from different variables to other groups and self

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyr

I've got some data from different assays (8 in total) and want to work out the R^2 between them all and to one another. So one result from one sample tested on one assay is compared to the same sample on the other 7 assays, as means to work out the correlation of all the assays to one another.

Example starting data is below:

```
    ID   Short_Id  Cohort Assay  AssayResult
  100001 RTP12       D     1      123
  100001 RTP12       D     2      456
  100001 RTP12       D     3      789
```

What I would like to do is modify the data frame so there are 2 'AssayResult' columns and 2 'Assay' columns like the following, where each group is compared to one another:

```
    ID   Short_Id  Cohort Assay1  AssayResult1  Assay2 AssayResult2  
  100001 RTP12       D     1      123             1        123
  100001 RTP12       D     2      456             1        123
  100001 RTP12       D     3      789             1        123
  ...
  100001 RTP12       D     1      123              3        789
  100001 RTP12       D     2      456              3        789
  100001 RTP12       D     3      789              3        789
```

As with this data frame, I could then run the below code, using AssayResult1 and AssayResult2 as X/Y axis and using Assay1 + Assay2 to facet_grid into a big 8x8 figure, allowing comparisons between all of them.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=AssayResult1, y=AssayResult2))+
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10")+
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10")+
  stat_poly_eq(formula = my.formula,rr.digits = 2,
                    label.x="right",label.y=c(0.10,10),
                    geom = "label_npc",alpha=0.33,
                    parse = TRUE)+
  facet_grid(Assay1~Assay2)
```

Part of me thinks this would be easy to do - but I'm not sure how best to do it via dplyr/tidyr. I could also be missing something super simple that I could run within ggplot to do this? As the data is all there, I just need a way to compare the "AssayResults" to one another based on the "Assay" field

Any help is appreciated!

**EDIT:** if there is also an easy way to produce a correlation comparison heatmap, that would also be nice. As I'm interested in the correlation between assays, but also visually seeing the comparisons between all the samples on these different assays.

Comment: it's not entirely clear that what you need. Look into `expand`. And make a Minimal-Reproducible example dataset to better illustrate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you're going for at all, but perhaps might help you define the question more specifically.

Here I make some fake data from the first 7 rows of `mtcars` and show how it could be joined to itself and plotted to do something at least vaguely similar to what you're looking for. You don't provide `my.formula` so I don't know that you're expecting for `stat_poly_eq`; in any case it would seem comparing one data point in a cohort against the others in the cohort would mean you'd only have one x value, no?

```
library(tidyverse)
mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
  slice(1:7) %>%
  arrange(cyl, wt) %>%
  select(Short_Id = car, Cohort = cyl, Assay_result = wt)

df <- mtcars1 %>%
  left_join(mtcars1, by = "Cohort")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Assay_result.x, y=Assay_result.y))+
  geom_point() +
  scale_y_continuous(trans="log10")+
  scale_x_continuous(trans="log10")+
  facet_grid(Short_Id.x~.)
```

[image]